# Multiply rows according to number

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe `crimes` containing crimes. My problem is, that there isn't one row per crime as it should be. Instead there's a variable `count` for the number of occurences of that crime.

```r
types <- c("Theft", "Robbery", "Assault", "Theft")
count <- c(3, 1, 2, 1)
crimes <- data.frame(type=types, count)
```

As to the data structure I cannot simply compute frequencies like `table(crimes$type)`. For thefts this would give me a frequency of two, but it should be four instead as the first theft is actually a summary of three thefts.

Is there a way to add additional rows according to the count-variable? I know that sometimes I could also simply sum up count-values per type of crime, but that's not what I want.

Comment: `crimes[rep(1:nrow(crimes), crimes$count), ]` or other variety of options in the link.

Comment: crimes %>% group_by(type) %>% summarize(Total_count=sum(count,na.rm=TRUE))